# How do I pickpocket an enemy?

Tags: mark-of-the-ninja

In one later level of Mark of the Ninja, I have the option of pickpocketing a key off of an enemy. How exactly do I do this? I am able to get right up to the enemy, but my only option seems to be to kill him. FWIW, I'm playing on the PC.

Is pickpocketing a skill I have to unlock?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't have to be unlocked, but it will only work in certain cases.

Assuming you're using the Xbox pad, just get (really) close to him, stealthy, and press the <kbd>B</kbd> (instead of <kbd>X</kbd>) button to steal instead of kill him.

Also, note that [some players had troubles with the stealing feature](http://steamcommunity.com/app/214560/discussions/0/882963336747859188/).

Comment: it also has issues with determining the correct distance.  Sometimes you have to back up a step before allowing to pick pocket.

Comment: Note that the video is broken

Answer (score 4):

Don't use "E" button. Instead use right mouse click. And once the animation begins with mouse (the show which way to pull it) once again pull it and right click it.